# Angular - Child component doesn't render data update from http request

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this components structure in app.component.html:

```
  <sidebar-container></sidebar-container>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Sidebar container is a component that belongs to another module (sidebar.module).
In the ngOnInit of the sidebarContainer component I have a property called "list" that's initiated as an empty array.

```
export class SidebarContainer implements OnInit {

  list: Array<any> = [];
  
  constructor(
   private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit():void {
  this.http.get('url').subscribe(
   res => this.list = res
  }
```

The list has this structure:

```
 [{id: 1, name: "Michael"}]
```

In Sidebar container component child I have only this template (sidebar is a component that has only a div for rendering the list passed as input):

```
<sidebar [list]="list"></sidebar>
```

Template of sidebar-component:

```
<div *ngFor="let l of list">{{l.id}}</div>
```

Now, when I launch the app and I try to debug data are not updated and I don't see anything. Http request starts when component is just loaded and ngfor seems not work. But when I initialized in the sidebar-component template a value of the array like this:

```
test -> {{list[0].id}}
<div *ngFor="let l of list">{{l.id}}</div>
```

I can see both of values.

I can't understand this situation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: only when i try to see element in this way {{list[0].id}} Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Component is loaded before http request is completed

Comment: component is loaded before http request is completed...and for the first time property 'id' is undefined....

Comment: You could try to change the `changeDetection` to `onPush` in the child component

Comment: The `changeDetection` is just to `onPush` in the sidebar-container-component and in the sidebar-component...

Answer (score 0):

In your template, put check condition if id is defined or not.

```
<div *ngFor="let l of list">{{l.hasOwnProperty('id')?l.id:''}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnPush Change Detection Strategy:

You can change the change detection strategy of the child component to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. This strategy tells Angular to only perform change detection when input properties of the component change or when an event is triggered within the component.
Update the child component's decorator with the following:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

By using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, the child component will only update when its input properties change or when explicitly triggered using ChangeDetectorRef.

Try these approaches and see if they resolve the issue of the child component not rendering data updates from the HTTP request